# Issue with the web.py tutorial when using sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, web.py

For the record, I have looked into this, but cannot seem to figure out what is wrong.

So I'm doing the tutorial on web.py, and I get to the database part (can do everything above it). I wanted to use sqlite3 for various reasons. Since I couldn't figure out where to type the

> sqlite3 test.db

line, I look into the sqlite3 module, and create a database with that. The code for that is:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
print("Opened database successfully");

conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE todo 
    (id serial primary key,
     title text,
     created timestamp default now(),
     done boolean default 'f');''')

conn.execute("INSERT INTO todo (title) VALUES ('Learn web.py')");
```

but I get the error

> done boolean default 'f');''')
>   sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error

I've tried looking into this, but cannot figure out for the life of me what the issue is.

I haven't had luck with other databases (new to this, so not sure on the subtleties), I wasn't able to just make the sqlite database directly so it might be a python thing, but it matches the tester.py I made with the [sqlite with python tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_python.htm)...

Thanks if anyone can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using SQLite but are specifying data types from some other database engine.  SQLite accepts only INT, TEXT, REAL, NUMERIC, and NONE.  Boolean is most likely being mapped to one of the number types and therefore `DEFAULT 'F'` is not valid syntax (although I don't think it would be valid in any version of SQL that *does* support BOOLEAN as a datatype, since they general use INTEGER for the underlying storage).

Rewrite the CREATE TABLE statement with SQLite datatypes and allowable default values and your code should work fine.

More details on the (somewhat unusual) SQLite type system: http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: Thanks, I found the default statements were incorrect as well. Removing them fixed the problem; I'll edit the question if I can't get them to work soon

Answer (score 1):

The problem causing the error is that you can't use the MySQL now() function here. Try instead

```
created default current_timestamp
```

This works:

```
conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE todo 
    (id serial primary key,
     title text,
     created default current_timestamp,
     done boolean default 'f');''')
```